# Scala shell interpreter with project dependencies

Tags: scala

I'm relatively new to Scala. I'd like to load all project dependencies into Scala shell interpreter in order to test somme coding. Is there any trick to simply do it?

Here is my build.sbt. Somme of those dependencies call for more then 38 other dependencies. Can't collect jars manually.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-all" % "2.2.4"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11"
```

Thanks in advance.

Saïd

Answer (score 2):

You can get a `REPL` with all dependencies of you `build.sbt` by calling `sbt console` in the directory containing the `build.sbt`.

### Buildfile: `build.sbt`

```
name := """example"""

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "biz.neumann" % "nice-uuid_2.11" % "1.1"
```

### REPL with lib usage example

#### Starting

```
$ sbt console
```

#### in the REPL

```
...
[info] Starting scala interpreter...

scala> import biz.neumann.NiceUUID._
import biz.neumann.NiceUUID._

scala> "9ecce884-47fe-4ba4-a1bb-1a3d71ed6530".uuid
res0: scala.util.Try[java.util.UUID] = Success(9ecce884-47fe-4ba4-a1bb-1a3d71ed6530)
```